# Creating command from some of the arguments to a bash script including whitespaces

Tags: bash, arguments, whitespace

I have a bash script that takes some arguments and uses some of them to loop over some action while some others (those of the form 'a=b') are passed to that action. Essentially, it looks like

```
args=
numbers=
for arg in "$@"; do
    if [[ "$arg" == *=* ]]; then
        args="$args $arg"
    else
        numbers="$numbers $arg"
    fi
done
for number in $numbers; do
    some_action $number $args
done
```

So, for example, if I call it as `script 1 2 3 a=b c=d`, it runs

```
some_action 1 a=b c=d
some_action 2 a=b c=d
some_action 3 a=b c=d
```

The problem is with whitespaces. Sometimes I need to pass arguments like `resume='5 8'`. Once they are stored in `$args`, the distinction between spaces and arguments is lost, a call to `script 1 2 resume='5 8'` results in

```
some_action 1 resume=5 8
some_action 2 resume=5 8
```

so `8` is a separate argument. I tried to create the `args` string with newlines, using `IFS='\n'`, but this somehow resulted in superfluous calls to `some_action`. Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: is calling: `script 1 2 resume="'5 8'"` an acceptable usage method? That's double quotes on the outside, with single quotes on the inside.  That provides the desired output internally